# Alternative way to check if CTRL+ALT+DEL screen is visible

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, windows-10

Currently I'm using the below code to test if the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> screen is visible and it is working as expected. The problem is that polling this info consumes CPU and I'm looking for an event based option. Does anyone know another way to detect if this screen is visible?

I only need to know when this screen is closed. I don't really care when it opens. Just that it had been open and is now closed.

To be honest, I found this code and I'm not exactly sure how it is specific, if at all, to the screen I'm referring to. It appears to look for any process creation and deletion events. What this means is that this screen must be opening a new process. Knowing that process name would be helpful too.

```
var interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3);
const string isWin32Process = "TargetInstance isa \"Win32_Process\"";

// Listen for started processes.
WqlEventQuery startQuery = new WqlEventQuery("__InstanceCreationEvent", interval, isWin32Process);
var _startWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(startQuery);
_startWatcher.Start();
_startWatcher.EventArrived += OnStartEventArrived;

// Listen for closed processes.
WqlEventQuery stopQuery = new WqlEventQuery("__InstanceDeletionEvent", interval, isWin32Process);
var _stopWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(stopQuery);
_stopWatcher.Start();
_stopWatcher.EventArrived += OnStopEventArrived;
```

What is the name of this screen? And how do I detect this type of window? It seems like the same type as the login window.

[image]

Comment: sounds like an x-y problem...

Comment: Yeah it is. I do think an answer could be helpful to other people. I don't know how else to ask this and I've searched for awhile. I'm not even sure the name of the screen I'm referring to.

Comment: Please, instead of down-voting, which nobody has yet, maybe help me reconstruct my question or give me some direction for me to search.

Comment: Just wondering why you are searching for the close event on that window?

Comment: I need to execute some code in order to correct a bug in my app. I use a keyboard hook and if the user brings up this screen using the key combination then my app isn't notified of the keys being depressed. Hence they stay pressed. This is a bug in which the way I am handling it in the first place I suppose, but I can't think of another way to implement it and needs this in the meantime. I must use a hook because I want to add hotkeys that can override Windows default.

Comment: This is the app in case you are wondering....https://github.com/mzomparelli/zVirtualDesktop

Comment: I don't think it's possible to in general as it would be a security risk. This is a OS controlled screen which when triggered by the `Ctrl+Alt+Del` combo is to be a way to guarantee you, as the user that whatever you're doing is going to be handled by the OS directly. If applications could somehow detect this, they could potentially do things to intercept or phish out extra interactions that could put the user's data at risk.

Comment: I don't see how detecting it would be a security risk. Overriding, which can't be done as far as I know, is different. I'm not even trying to intercept the CTRL+ALT+DELETE keys because we all know that doesn't work.

Comment: Still, suppose one could detect the combo, an app can go and spoof the screen upon detection. When the user goes away from the real screens, it'll go away and they'd be presented with the spoofed screens. Then they may try to dismiss or otherwise interact with the screens and potentially give away their passwords or other personal information. Why risk it in the first place?

Comment: You're right, I could create a screen just like it after it closes. I guess that would make it a security risk. Nonetheless, the code I posted checks for process creation and it solves an issue for me with this screen. This means I could detect it if knew the process.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd>, Windows switches to a another special virtual desktop<sup>a</sup> that hosts the `winlogon` process that is responsible for user login/logoff/lock etc. actions. By using the WinAPI function [`SetWinEventHook`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318066(v=vs.85).aspx) with the [`EVENT_SYSTEM_DESKTOPSWITCH`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318066(v=vs.85).aspx) argument you can set up a callback function that is called whenever such a desktop switch occurs:

```
//Store the callback in a variable so that it is not GC'd
private static readonly WinEventDelegate callback = EventCallback;
static void StartListeningForDesktopSwitch()
{
    SetWinEventHook(EVENT_SYSTEM_DESKTOPSWITCH, EVENT_SYSTEM_DESKTOPSWITCH,
        IntPtr.Zero, callback, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNTHREAD);
}

static void EventCallback(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType,
       IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Desktop switched");
}
```

**Note:** If you want to use this in a console application, you have to add a message loop by adding a hidden `Form`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{        
    StartListeningForDesktopSwitch(); 

    // Run message loop
    Application.Run(new HiddenForm());
}

private class HiddenForm : Form
{
    public HiddenForm()
    {
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    }
}

delegate void WinEventDelegate(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType,
    IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread,
    uint dwmsEventTime);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SetWinEventHook(uint eventMin, uint eventMax, IntPtr
    hmodWinEventProc, WinEventDelegate lpfnWinEventProc, uint idProcess,
    uint idThread, uint dwFlags);

const uint WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT = 0x0000;
const uint WINEVENT_SKIPOWNTHREAD = 0x0001;
const uint EVENT_SYSTEM_DESKTOPSWITCH = 0x0020;
```

---

**Further**:  The desktop switch also occurs when the user pressed <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> or a UAC window pops up. Thus, we need a way to detect these other cases. The UAC case is rather trivial, it is enough to check if the process `consent.exe` is running during the callback function:

```
var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("consent");
if (processes.Length == 0)
    Console.WriteLine("This is not a UAC prompt");
```

The other case, unfortunately, is a bit more complicated. I have only managed to detect wheter a user returns from a lock screen, but not whether they enter it (as you said, this is not relevant for you, but I wanted to mention it anyway).

Detecting whether the session is locked can be done by listening for the 
[`SystemEvents.SessionSwitch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionswitch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event in our `HiddenForm`. The [`SessionSwitchEventArgs.Reason`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.win32.sessionswitcheventargs.reason(v=vs.110).aspx) property is set to `SessionSwitchReason.SessionLock` if this is a lock event, and to `SessionSwitchReason.SessionUnlock` if the user unlocks. We only can tell whether a desktop switch was not to the lock screen desktop when we are switching back to the default desktop since the switch desktop event callbacks are called *before* a session lock and *after* a session unlock. This leads to the following code for a sample console application:

```
private static readonly WinEventDelegate callback = EventCallback;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SetWinEventHook(EVENT_SYSTEM_DESKTOPSWITCH,
        EVENT_SYSTEM_DESKTOPSWITCH, IntPtr.Zero, callback, 0, 0,
        WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNTHREAD);

    Application.Run(new HiddenForm());
}

private class HiddenForm : Form
{
    public HiddenForm()
    {
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += SystemEvents_SessionSwitch;
    }

    private void SystemEvents_SessionSwitch(object sender, SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Reason == SessionSwitchReason.SessionUnlock)
            wasUnlocked = true;
    }
}

static bool wasUnlocked = false;
static bool wasOpened = false;

static void EventCallback(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType,
    IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime)
{
    // Check if UAC dialog is being shown
    var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("consent");
    if (processes.Length == 0)
    {
        if (wasOpened)
        {
            if (!wasUnlocked)
                Console.WriteLine("Exited from CTRL+ALT+DEL");
            wasUnlocked = false;
            wasOpened = false;
        }
        else
            wasOpened = true;
    }
}

delegate void WinEventDelegate(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType,
    IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread,
    uint dwmsEventTime);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SetWinEventHook(uint eventMin, uint eventMax, IntPtr
    hmodWinEventProc, WinEventDelegate lpfnWinEventProc, uint idProcess,
    uint idThread, uint dwFlags);

const uint WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT = 0x0000;
const uint WINEVENT_SKIPOWNTHREAD = 0x0001;
const uint EVENT_SYSTEM_DESKTOPSWITCH = 0x0020;
```

---

<sup>a</sup> This type of virtual desktop has nothing to do with the newly introduced "virtual desktop" feature in Windows 10

Comment: This looks promising. I'm going to try it out, thanks!

Comment: I get this error when trying to set this up. I'm using this in a class with the PInvoke declarations and the first block of code you posted. `A callback was made on a garbage collected delegate of type 'zVirtualDesktop!zVirtualDesktop.Internal.Hook.WindowEventHook+WinEventDelegate::Invoke`

Comment: How do I keep it alive?

Comment: turns out the delegate wasn't staying alive in debug, but is in release. The problem now is that this only triggers one time per application run. On the second time it ceases to call the Callback method.

Comment: Also, seems to create a memory leak sometimes.

Comment: I created a question for this issue I'm having with your code. Please help.....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44875879/setwineventhook-only-hitting-callback-once-per-app-run

Comment: @MichaelZ. Is this a console app? Do you have the message loop?

Comment: It is a WinForms app. Let me try moving the method call to my main form class.

Comment: The callback gets executed once per app run. Then I get nothing until I restart the app. The fact that it gets execute once means there is a message pump, right?

Comment: Yeah. Does it help if you put `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]` before the `lpfnWinEventProc` parameter in `SetWinEventHook`?

Comment: You could also try to add a separate static delegate variable that points to the callback. You need to prevent the delegate's garbage collection.

Comment: I tried moving the delegate to another class that has a static declaration of the delegate and I get the same problem. Even more concerning than it only executing once is that it's sometimes generating an `AccessViolationException`. I think you did well with this answer. Earn another one with the other question then come back here and update this answer if needed.

Comment: I changed your first code box a little. I added a variable to hold the callback function so that it does not get GC'd.

Comment: @MichaelZ. ok great. just as i suggested :)

Comment: @MichaelZ. by the way, I failed to realize that the session switch stuff and the message pump was already implemented in .NET. I edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this might help. This won't check if the screen is there bur rather if the events have been triggered, to do that you might need to enable the logging of these events, you can do it by opening the group policy editor:

`gpedit.msc` → *Computer Configuration*  → *Windows Settings*  → *Security Settings*  → *Advanced Audit Policy Configuration*  → *System Audit Policies* → *Local Group Policy Object* → *Logon/Logoff*  → *Audit Other Login/Logoff Events*

After it has been enabled, you could listen for the event id `4800` for locking and `4801` for unlocking.

Comment: I can test for lock and unlock already. This is a different screen. Also, this is a public app so I can't rely on events needing to be enabled in group policy. Thanks for the answer though. It might help someone else.

Comment: I thought I could handle this window with `SessionSwitchReason` like the lock and unlock, but it doesn't work. I have to handle this particular window another way.

Comment: BTW, I think the name that you are looking for is officially called GINA, other than the much more common "Ctrl Alt Del" screen. (Graphical IdentificatioN and Authentication). 

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721584(v=vs.85).aspx#_security_gina_gly

Comment: I thought GINA was gone in Win10, but thanks for that tip. I'll dig into that.

Comment: Looks like it comes disabled by default in Windows 10 but it can be enabled back!

Comment: I don't understand then. The screen is there without GINA. Do you understand the code that I put in the question? How is that detecting it?

Comment: I get that the code is querying the events, but I don't see how it is specific to this screen.

Comment: Well, from what I understand from the code, you are using the Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) infrastructure which listens for processes which start and shut down, right?

But I don't see where are you specifically listening for a specific process? e.g. (logonui.exe). Is part of the code missing?

Comment: That's what it appears to be doing. So that means that a new process is created when this screen pops up. Any idea what that process is?

Comment: None of the code is missing. This handles my issue, but I suppose I wouldn't notice if the code ran for any process. Maybe there is a better way to listen for processes being created? Better yet, this specific process, whatever it is.

Comment: It seems that it is called winlogon, I don't have Windows 10 running right now on this machine but that's what I found out online. 

Also, you need to add something for OnStopEventArrived otherwise you would't be passing any process to it...

Something like:

void OnStopEventArrived( object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e )
{
    var o = (ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent[ "TargetInstance" ];
    string name = (string)o[ "Name" ];

    ...
}

Comment: Yes, I have the event handler methods. They aren't relevant and you can assume they are there. Thanks for the tip again. I'll try testing for that process.