# Get notified when user left Ctrl+Alt+Del (SAS/SAK) screen

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to get notified in .net c# when the user left the Ctrl+Alt+Del (SAS/SAK) screen?

I don't want to block this key combination. The user can still use every function (open Task-Manager, change user, etc.) in the Ctrl+Alt+Del screen.

I already know how to detect when the key combination is pressed by the user.

Thanks for any kind of help.

**EDIT:**

Solution for me is [Alternative way to check if CTRL+ALT+DEL screen is visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44866543/alternative-way-to-check-if-ctrlaltdel-screen-is-visible)

Comment: Do you need an event or is polling acceptable?  When the normal desktop becomes active, paint events are going to be sent to visible windows.  For specifically asking "Is the secure desktop active" you'll need the Window Station and Desktop API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681928(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @BenVoigt It doesnt matter wheter event or polling. Are the paint events available in WPF? Anyway, i found a solution for my problem, thanks.